# How to call a custom function with exponentiation for every element of a matrix in GNU Octave?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, linear-algebra, exponentiation

Trying to find a way to call the exponentiation function ( ^ ) used in a custom function for every item in a matrix in GNU Octave.

I am quite a beginner, and I suppose that this is very simple, but I can't get it to work.

**The code looks like this:**

```
function result = the_function(the_val)
    result = (the_val - 5) ^ 2
endfunction
```

**I have tried to call it like this:**

```
>> A = [1,2,3];
>> the_function(A);
>> arrayfun(@the_function, A);
>> A .@the_function 2;
```

None of these have worked (the last one I believe is simply not correct syntax), throwing the error:

```
error: for A^b, A must be a square matrix
```

This, I guess, means it is trying to square the *matrix*, not the elements inside of it.

How should I do this?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Can't you use `A.^b`? That works in Matlab

Comment: That was actually an error in my phrasing.  If you notice, I first need to subtract 5 from the element, _then_ exponentiate it.  Otherwise, that would be a good solution.  Sorry about the mixup :S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct to call the function as `the_function(A)`, but you have to make sure the function can handle a vector input. As you say, `(the_val - 5)^2` tries to square the matrix (and it thus gives an error if `the_val` is not square). To compute an *element-wise* power you [use `.^`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/power.html) instead of `^`.

So: in the definition of your function, you need to change

```
result = (the_val-5)^2;
```

to

```
result = (the_val-5).^2;
```

As an additional note, since your code as it stands does work with *scalar* inputs, you could also use the `arrayfun` approach. The correct syntax would be (remove the `@`):

```
arrayfun(the_function, A)
```

However, using `arrayfun` is usually slower than defining your function such that it works directly with vector inputs (or "*vectorizing*" it). So, whenever possible, [vectorize your function](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html). That's what my `.^`suggestion above does.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the suggestion, and for providing a way for the custom-defined function to work.  I incorrectly assumed that what Octave did was somehow call my function for every item, but through your clarification I now understand how that doesn't make sense.  Cheers! :)